# How to remove a default value in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

SQL>alter table modify (deptname varchar2(20) default 'not available');

i have added this default value to my table. how to remove it so that implicit null values can again be provided by oracle.

Comment: First do an UPDATE to null then alter it to DEFAULT NULL

Comment: You cannot remove the default, you can only change it so it defaults to null. (Which is almost, but not quite, the same thing).

Comment: @Mihai - why do you need to update all the existing values to null just to set the default to null? Changing the default shouldn't affect existing data. (Unless it's a new column added with a default value, which isn't the case here)

Comment: `ALTER SOME_TABLE MODIFY (DEPTNAME DEFAULT NULL)` should effectively remove the default value.

Comment: @AlexPoole The question is a bit ambiguous the OP makes it sound like he wants to change all values already set to NULL.